# Disconnect signals for QGis plugin with dialog created by Qt Designer

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qgis, pyqgis

I'm working on a plugin for QGis 3.x. The UI was created with Qt Designer and the plugin code boilerplate by `Plugin builder`.

I do have 3 main files in my project :

- `my_plugin.py` with the main `MyPlugin` class and `initGui()`, `unload()` and `run()` methods
- `my_plugin_dialog.py` with a simple `MyPluginDialog` class, that inherits from `QtWidgets.QDialog` and the `FORM_CLASS` based on my `.ui` designer file. The class only contains `__init__()` method, itself calling `self.setupUi()`
- an UI file created by Qt Designer `my_plugin_dialog_base.ui`

I encounter some issues related to duplicate signals when starting/closing the plugin dialog.
The most similar discussion on SO is the following : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137160/qgis-plugin-triggers-function-twice

Yet, my problem is that my dialog object is created within the `run()` method (see below), so I can't access to my UI elements in the `initGui()` nor `unload()` methods.

So how can I disconnect signals, or define them so that closing the plugin also disconnects all my signals ?

Here is an excerpt of `my_plugin.py` content (*created by `Plugin Builder`, except the last line related to connecting the signal and the slot*) :

```py
def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

        icon_path = ':/plugins/my_plugin/icon.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u'Start My Plugin'),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

        # will be set False in run()
        self.first_start = True

def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""

        # Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
        # Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the plugin is started
        if self.first_start == True:
            self.first_start = False
            self.dlg = MyPluginDialog()
        self.dlg.push_button_start.clicked.connect(self.on_pb_start) # connect signal to slot
```

And `my_plugin_dialog.py`:

```py
FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'small_etl_dialog_base.ui'))

class MyPluginDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(MyPluginDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer through FORM_CLASS.
        # After self.setupUi() you can access any designer object by doing
        # self.<objectname>, and you can use autoconnect slots - see
        # http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html
        # #widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect
        self.setupUi(self)
```

Maybe there is a proper way to access dialog objects inside the `initGui()` method ?

Comment: Just connect the signal when you create the dialog: move the signal connection in the same indentation level as `self.dlg = MyPluginDialog()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you connect your signal every time the `run` method is called. However, you only create your dialog once guarded by a Boolean variable.

The solution is to only connect your signal when you create the dialog, so something like this would work better:

```
def run(self):
    ...
    if self.first_start == True:
        self.first_start = False
        self.dlg = MyPluginDialog()
        self.dlg.push_button_start.clicked.connect(self.on_pb_start)
    ...
```

Also, note that you do not necessarily need the `self.first_start` boolean guard. You could always check whether self.dlg is not `None` instead.

So, you could tidy this up a bit by something like this:

```
def run(self):
    ...
    if not self.dlg:
        self.dlg = MyPluginDialog()
        self.dlg.push_button_start.clicked.connect(self.on_pb_start)
    ...
```